# Is there any impact wrapping using statement in static methods

Tags: c#, functional-programming, c#-6.0, c#-7.0

Without getting embroiled in the opinions from an aesthetic point of view lets focus on what are the technical implications of the following.

I am a big fan of using expression bodied methods for simple methods and properties as well as method chaining. IMO they look nice and clean without the excess noise of the curly braces (Yes I also use F#).

However you are not able to use expression bodied methods for methods containing a using statement. Without focusing on the specifics of the syntax below what, if any, would the technical implications be of doing something **like** the following:

```
class ...
{
  HttpClient client;

  public async Task SaveSomething(X value) =>
    Using
     .Disposable(await client.PostAsync("..", value))
     .Act(response => response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode());

  public async Task<X> GetSomething() =>
    await Using
     .Disposable(await client.GetAsync(".."))
     .Act(response => response.ReadAsAsync<X>());
}
```

Static wrapper implementation:

```
static class Using
{
  public static DisposableAct<TDisposable> Disposable<TDisposable>(TDisposable disposable)
    where TDisposable : IDisposable => new DisposableAct<TDisposable>(disposable);
}

class DisposableAct<TDisposable> where TDisposable : IDisposable
{
  private readonly TDisposable disposable;

  public DisposableAct(TDisposable disposable) => this.disposable = disposable;

  public TResult Act<TResult>(Func<TDisposable, TResult> act)
  {
    using (disposable)
    {
      return act(disposable);
    }
  }
}
```

As opposed to:

```
class ...
{
  HttpClient client;

  public async Task SaveSomething(X value)
  {
    using (var response = await client.PostAsync("..", value))
    {
      response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    }
  }

  public Task<X> GetSomething()
  {
    using (var response = await client.PostAsync("..", value))
    {
      return await response.ReadAsAsync<X>();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: No one can accurately speak to the technical implications of code you're refusing to provide.  How, *precisely*, you implement it affects the implications of using it.

Answer (score 2):

There are numerous differences between your wrapper and the code you're attempting to replicate.

1. You dispose of the disposable resource as soon as the `async` method returns, rather than after the asynchronous operation finishes.  The code you're attempting to replicate doesn't dispose of the resource until after the asynchronous operation finishes.  If you ever use the disposable resource after awaiting anything, it will already be disposed.
2. If an exception happens before you call `Act`, the disposable resource is leaked.  There is no such opportunity to leak the disposable resource in the other code.
3. If you call `Act` multiple times the disposable resource will already have been disposed.
4. If you never call `Act` on the wrapper then the disposable resource is never disposed.  This is basically #2, but if the author of the code does it wrong.
5. You're creating multiple additional objects, adding increased memory pressure.  There's both your disposable wrapper, as well as additional `async` methods, meaning additional state machines.

#1 is something that you can fix in your implementation without needing to change how callers use it, the others are inherent to the way you've designed this, and addressing those would require changing the way that callers use the operation fairly significantly to fix.

So as far as fixing all of these things go, the first thing would be to just remove the wrapper object entirely.  It creates numerous opportunities for the programmer to just do it wrong (#3, #4, and some others I didn't bother to mention), and is a big part of #5.  Instead just have a static method accept two arguments, a disposable resource and an action to take on it.  That gives you the control you need to ensure it's *always* (or at least closer to always) done correctly.

```
public static TResult UseDisposable<TDisposable, TResult>(TDisposable disposable, Func<TDisposable, TResult> function)
    where TDisposable : IDisposable
{
    using (disposable)
    {
        return function(disposable);
    }
}
```

Next, if you want to support asynchronous methods, you need to have a specifically overload *just* for that, in which you realize that it's an asynchronous method and handle it accordingly.  Fortunately `await` makes this easy to write.  (Note that technically using `async` here means we're creating a state machine that we could technically avoid if we did it by hand.  If you wanted to avoid that difference from the original you'd either need to do the whole thing by hand (which is surprisingly hard if you want to ensure that all of the right error handling and cancellation behavior is done correctly).  If you can live with the added allocations, then the code isn't too much more complex than the code you're trying to replicate.

```
public static async Task<TResult> UseDisposable<TDisposable, TResult>(TDisposable disposable, Func<TDisposable, Task<TResult>> function)
    where TDisposable : IDisposable
{
    using (disposable)
    {
        return await function(disposable);
    }
}
```

Then of course you need versions of those two overloads for non-result returning operations:

```
public static void UseDisposable<TDisposable>(TDisposable disposable, Action<TDisposable> action)
    where TDisposable : IDisposable
{
    using (disposable)
    {
        action(disposable);
    }
}
public static async Task UseDisposable<TDisposable, TResult>(TDisposable disposable, Func<TDisposable, Task> action)
    where TDisposable : IDisposable
{
    using (disposable)
    {
        await action(disposable);
    }
}
```

It's worth noting at this point that the above overloads don't completely address the possibility of exceptions taking place before the disposable resources gets into the `using`.  The above version shrinks the window of possibilities over your code, and in particular removes a lot of possible mis-uses of it, but it doesn't eliminate it entirely.  If you're concerned about it, you can take things one step further an, rather than accepting a disposable resource, you can accept a method that *generates* the disposable resource.  This removes that possibility entirely.  Fortunately all of these overloads can sit side by side, so you can have all of these overloads and then only use the disposable generator versions when you're concerned about possible exceptions happening at any place between it's constructor and the start of the using.

```
public static TResult UseDisposable<TDisposable, TResult>(Func<TDisposable> disposableGenerator, Func<TDisposable, TResult> function)
    where TDisposable : IDisposable
{
    using (var disposable = disposableGenerator())
    {
        return function(disposable);
    }
}
public static async Task<TResult> UseDisposable<TDisposable, TResult>(Func<TDisposable> disposableGenerator, Func<TDisposable, Task<TResult>> function)
    where TDisposable : IDisposable
{
    using (var disposable = disposableGenerator())
    {
        return await function(disposable);
    }
}
public static void UseDisposable<TDisposable>(Func<TDisposable> disposableGenerator, Action<TDisposable> action)
    where TDisposable : IDisposable
{
    using (var disposable = disposableGenerator())
    {
        action(disposable);
    }
}
public static async Task UseDisposable<TDisposable, TResult>(Func<TDisposable> disposableGenerator, Func<TDisposable, Task> action)
    where TDisposable : IDisposable
{
    using (var disposable = disposableGenerator())
    {
        await action(disposable);
    }
}
```

You might also want to make the original 4 overloads extension methods, if you go the route of using those over the later four, and you find you're using them enough for it to make sense.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback, the implementation was rushed, I get your points if the implementation was used outside of the constraints that I am suggesting. Point two could be mitigated by injecting in a func for the disposable. I am really more interested at the implications at a lower level.